# IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> to string[][]

Tags: c#, linq

How do I cast a `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` to a `string[][]` or a `List<string[]>`?

I already tried `.toArray` and .`SelectMany` but they seem to create either `string[]` or `List<IEnumerable<string>>` which is not what I really want.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `Select` to map each inner `IEnumerable<string>` to a `string[]`:

```
string[][] arrayOfStringArrays = enumerable.Select(innerEnumerable => innerEnumerable.ToArray()).ToArray();
```